# Select all count(*) and sum(*) transactions based on merchant(business) table conditions

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, database

I have two table

1. transaction [ foreign key- profileid ] and
2. business [primary key- profileid ]

I want all record in transactions where business.merchant_type is 'AQ'.

What query I need to make to full fill above criteria.

`

```
SELECT COUNT( CASE WHEN  bp.merchant_type='AQ' AND tm.profileid = bp.profileid THEN tm.txnid END ) AS  'Enterprise Total Txn count',
SUM( CASE WHEN bp.merchant_type='AQ' AND tm.profileid = bp.profileid THEN tm.PG_TXN_AMOUNT END ) AS 'Enterprise Total Txn Amount',
CASE WHEN tm.TXN_STATUS='1' THEN COUNT(
CASE WHEN bp.merchant_type='AQ' AND tm.profileid = bp.profileid THEN tm.TXNID END
) END AS 'Enterprise Sucess Txn count',

CASE WHEN tm.TXN_STATUS='1' THEN SUM(
CASE WHEN  bp.merchant_type='AQ' AND tm.profileid = bp.profileid THEN tm.TXNID END
) END AS 'Enterprise Sucess Txn Amount'
FROM
tbl_business_profiles bp,tbl_transaction_master tm;
```

`

output
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U3ZoQ.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: As per one table name transactions which had multiple transactions record but I need only that information that has merchant acccount type is  'AQ'.

relation between transaction and merchat(business table) is of profileid column.

Comment: Need count(*) and sum(amount) from transaction table.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select * from transaction as tr left join business as bs 
on tr.profileid = bs.profileid
where bs.merchant_type = 'AQ'
```